# Add two columns with each other

Tags: python, pandas

Assume this is my `df` I am looking for a way to add one column with another.
For example:
Except `"col a"` every thing else should be add with each other
`colb + colc, cold + cole, colf + colg, colh + coli`

```
        a       b    c      d       e       f      g       h        i
group                                   
   A    0.15    0.1  0.1    0.15    0.15    0.1    0.1    0.10      0.05
   B    0.13    NaN  NaN    NaN     0.40    0.2    NaN    0.13      0.06
```

desired output:

```
          a      b      d        f      h    
group                                   
   A    0.15    0.2    0.30     0.2    0.15    
   B    0.13    NaN    0.40     0.2    0.19
```

I know I can manually add both the columns but I'm looking for a easier way or a apply function to achieve the output.

I couldn't figure out a way. Any help?

Comment: `df['b'] = df['b'] + df['c']` or `df['d'] = df['d'] + df['e']` use this.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey I knew this way but I was looking for something more efficient.

Comment: thats in answer of @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) of [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed `DataFrame` with no first column selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or removed by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), last filter by list of columns names:

```
cols = ['a','b','d','f','h']
df = df.add(df.iloc[:, 1:].shift(-1,axis=1), fill_value=0)[cols]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.add(df.drop('a', axis=1).shift(-1,axis=1), fill_value=0)[cols]

print (df)
          a    b    d    f     h
group                           
A      0.15  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.15
B      0.13  NaN  0.4  0.2  0.19
```

Comment: Can I know what `fill_value` really does here?

Comment: @user456 - Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for successful DataFrame alignment, with this value before computation. If data in both corresponding DataFrame locations is missing the result will be missing, check difference by `(df + df.drop('a', axis=1).shift(-1,axis=1))[cols]`